# XSD none, one, or both

Tags: xml, xsd

I searched a whole bunch and couldn't find any questions similar to this before posting. I'm working on creating an XSD and one complexType has these requirements:

- The element can have neither field
- The element can have field one
- If the element has field two it must also have field one

It essentially works out to "none, one(but a specific one), or both" but I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly and any help would be appreciated

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fieldOne" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fieldOne" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="fieldTwo" maxOccurs="1"/>             
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with an optional sequence:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="fieldOne"/>
        <xs:element name="fieldTwo" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The only way for a `fieldTwo` to be present is for the sequence to occur once, in which case `fieldOne` is required as well.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for the speedy response!